# Kohana 3.2 validate composite primary key

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana, kohana-3.2

I have following table

```
create table `groupusers`(
 `id` int not null auto_increment,
 `user` varchar(100) not null,
 `group` varchar(100) not null,
 UNIQUE KEY(`id`),
 PRIMARY KEY(`user`, `group`)
)
```

My model looks like this,

```
class Model_Groupuser extends ORM{
    protected $_table_name = 'groupusers';

    public function rules(){
        return array(
                'user' => array(
                        array('not_empty'),
                        array(array($this, 'user_group_not_exists')),
                ),
                'group' => array(
                        array('not_empty'),
                        array(array($this, 'user_group_not_exists')),
                )
        );
    }

    public function user_group_not_exists($param){
        // Need to get other field's value here.
    }
}
```

Problem is every time `user_group_not_exists` is called, its called with a single parameter. Either user or group. But I need both to determine if the combination exists in the db already.

How can I get current model's fields' value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get other fields value using `$this->object()` function.

```
public function user_group_not_exists($user_or_group){
    $obj = $this->object();
    $group = $obj['group'];
    $user = $obj['user'];

    // Check if ($group, $user) pair exists in db here
}
```

Comment: Is it impossible to pass both values as parameters?

Comment: valuators validate only a single field.

Answer (score -1):

You have not really named your table columns comfortable. Naming them `user` and `group` and the relations also `user` and `group` creates ambiguity between the two.

As kohana does this great thing where you can access table fields, relationships etc. as if it's an objects property. `$i_am_lazy = $object-><field,relation,whatever>`. Now you named your fields and relations such that it is not clear what you are trying to get.

The only way you can access these id's now is like the following (or the hard way through `$this->object()` as stated in the other answer, both don't feel good anyway):

```
$user  = $this->user->id;
$group = $this->group->id;
```

Though, I recommend just renaming the table columns.

```
create table `groupusers`(
    `id` int not null auto_increment,
    `user_id` varchar(100) not null,
    `group_id` varchar(100) not null,
    UNIQUE KEY(`id`),
    PRIMARY KEY(`user`, `group`)
)
```

That way you can simply use `$this->user_id` or `$this->group_id`.

Comment: Not following the naming convention is not a problem. You can define the column and table name in model too which overrides the convention.

Comment: Ofcourse you can, but with things like this you are only making it harder for yourself. Why use `$this->object()` ALWAYS when you can simply rename your columns ONE TIME.

Comment: The issue here is not related to kohana ORM naming convention. In the original project I have used the convention. I am showing here an example. And there is no relation here. Just a simple SINGLE table.